# One problem on Classical Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image][image: I'm wondering why in this problem I can't apply newton second law? The mass m of the moving part will be the mass solved in the problem.]

I'm wondering why in this problem I can't apply newton second law? The mass $m$ of the moving part will be the mass solved in the problem.

Comment: Add a the figure referenced in the problem, otherwise it's impossible for us to say anything about the question.

Comment: @TylerOlsen Just did it.

Comment: Stop putting this question on hold! This is not a homework, ok? Did you guys read a textbook ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is: you can apply Newton's law $dp/dt= F = mg - T$, but you can't assume $dp/dt = m dv/dt$ as $dm/dt$ is nonzero.

The fundamental law in Newtonian dynamics is **the object's rate of change in momentum equals the net force exerted on it**. Only in the special case of a constant mass object can this be translated into a statement about mass times acceleration being equal to the net force.

Comment: I noticed this, but what you mean is dp/dt = F is more fundamental than Newton second law? I'm just confused about which principle I should first consider.

Comment: @Lawerance - yes, the fundamental law in classical dynamics is the statement that the change in momentum equals the net force. In case of a constant mass object this can be transformed in a statement about acceleration.

Comment: Close.  Think of the integral of a Riemann sum over area elements $\delta s$.  $V=\frac{1]{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum X\,\delta x$.  What would $X$ be?

Comment: Wow, my browser just did something weird, and dropped that answer into the box, and then didn't let me delte or edit it.

Comment: @Johannes I hope you meant to say "*rate of change* of momentum equals the net force".  Also, you have to add the phrase "for a closed system". Newton's second law applies only to systems for which the mass is constant.  $\mathrm{d}p/\mathrm{d}t = F_\mathrm{net}$ is **not** correct if the mass is changing,  but $F_\mathrm{net}= ma$ is.

Comment: @garyp - thanks. Edited the text putting $dp/dt=F$ in words and phrased it more carefully. However, I am puzzled by your last remark. You seem to be saying $F=ma$ is more fundamental than $F=dp/dt$?

Comment: f I say $F_\mathrm{net}=dp/dt$ and allow a variable mass, I could then say $F_\mathrm{net}=d(mv)/dt=m\,dv/dt+v\,dm/dt$, but this last expression is incorrect. Consider a rocket traveling in space at constant $v$. The rocket is firing two thrusters, each pointing perpendicular to the direction of motion, and opposite to one another. Net force is zero, and velocity is constant, but the rocket is losing mass. Applying that formula gives $0=v\,dm/dt$.

Comment: @garyp - in the scenario you describe $dp/dt = F_{net} = 0$ is correct. The total mass and the centre of mass momentum are all constant.

Comment: @Johannes Yes, if you choose your system to be all of the exhaust gas / spent fuel that is removed from the rocket.  In that case the system is closed (w.r.t. mass), and the mass is constant.  If you choose your system to be the rocket plus remaining fuel, $\mathrm{d}m/\mathrm{d}t \neq 0$, and  $\mathrm{d}p/\mathrm{d}t = F_\mathrm{net}$ is invalid.

Comment: @garyp - if you choose your system to be the rocket plus remaining fuel you have to include not only the mass loss, but also the associated momentum loss, $dp/dt = F_{net}$ remains valid.